# Козак и казак

Tags: орфография

Никак не могу разобраться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, всегда ли пишется "казак" через А - и запорожские ка(о)заки и донские. Или запорожские - через О? Просто, по-украински, по-моему, через О, а как в русском? И, если написание различается, то почему такое разночтение?
Извините за путанный вопрос и заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У Фасмера:

[казак | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/40357/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA)

Казак -каза́к а́-, укр. коза́к, др.-русск. козакъ "работник, батрак", впервые в грам. 1395 г.; см. Срезн. I, 1173 и сл. Из укр. заимств. польск. kоzаk "казак". Ударение в форме мн. ч. каза́ки – результат влияния польско-укр. формы; оренб. казаки говорят: казаки́; см. Зеленин, РФВ, 56, 239. Заимств. из тур., крым.-тат., казах., кирг., тат., чагат. kаzаk "свободный, независимый человек, искатель приключений, бродяга". Сюда же каза́ки мн., соврем. каза́хи – тюрк. народ. Этноним касо́г не родствен каза́к, вопреки Эльи (505).

Получается, что русское и украинское "козак" - из древнерусского. В украинском  осталось О, в русском, вероятно, под влиянием аканья стало казак, а козак - устаревшее, в худ. произведениях (Гоголь) используется для передачи духа того времени,тогда так говорили.

В современном русском норма - казак.

Answer (score -1):

В русском языке существует только слово "казак". Написание через -о  смахивает на кальку, заимствованную в украинском языке.